# Why does this MapReduce mapping function emit not work?

Tags: mapreduce, cloudant

I have a Cloudant database with documents that use the following format:

```
{
  "_id": "0ea1ac7d5ef28860abc7030444515c4c",
  "_rev": "1-362058dda0b8680a818b38e9c68c5389",
  "text": "text-data",
  "time-data": 1452988105,
  "time-text": "3:48 PM - 16 Jan 2016",
  "link": "http://url/to/website"
}
```

I'm trying to create a view to easily count documents between a start and end `time-data`. However, this mapping function results in a query returning "No Documents Found":

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc.time-data, 1);
}
```

... while this does:

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc._id, 1);
}
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the name of your field. It contains a dash: `-`

Javascript interprets this as:

```
return doc.time - data
return doc.time minus data
```

You can either change your property (to something like `time_data`), or you can create your view like this:

```
function (doc) {
    if (doc['time-data']) {
        emit(doc['time-data'], 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, gosh. I'm rather embarrassed for being so caught up on it being a misunderstanding of Cloudant's views or MapReduce. Thanks so much!

Comment: You shouldn't be! It took me a little while to figure out what was going on as well.